# Creating a Pegboard in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a game for fun in python. I want to be able to make something that looks like this if n=10.

```
--------------------------------------------------
(1) (2)  (3)  (4)  (5)  (6)  (7)  (8)  (9)  (10)  
--------------------------------------------------
```

with the dotted lines above and below. I keep getting an error message and cannot get it to work. It seems like an easy enough piece of code and I was wondering if I could get some help.

This is my first time posting on this website so all help would be encouraged. Thank you!

Comment: What is the error message? Where is your code?

Comment: Could you please re-word your question? It should contain a [short, self-contained, correct, example](http://sscce.org/); a clear description of what the problem is and a description of [what you have tried](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) when attempting to fix the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> def PegBoard(n):
    print "-----"*n
    print ("({})  "*n).format(*range(1,n+1))
    print "-----"*n


>>> PegBoard(10)
--------------------------------------------------
(1)  (2)  (3)  (4)  (5)  (6)  (7)  (8)  (9)  (10)  
--------------------------------------------------
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a piece of code who should do what you need:

```
def pegboard(size):
    print "-"*size*4
    for i in range(1, size+1):
        print "(%d)" % i,
    print
    print "-"*size*4

pegboard(10)
```

I started recently here too, this is a great community don't be discouraged :)

Comment: this helps a lot but now it prints vertically and i need it to print horizonatly.